# Can Esri ASCII Input files be Aligned with Track Heading in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, import, esri-ascii-raster

Using QGIS to input [Esri ASCII](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009t0000000z000000) data files, I uploaded many small files, each file representing a second of data: 16 sensors X 25 lines. Each file uploaded creates a small rectangle on my larger map layer. The default MAP Orientation of Esri ascii files is with the Top edge of the rectangle facing North and Right/Left sides pointing Directly North. I want to ROTATE this MAP rectangle, during INPUT, so the Right/Left edges would be at an Angle to North.  Is there a command line option that allows this?

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to understand the issue if you could add an image.

Comment: To visualize my problem, imagine Scrabble tiles laid out on a grid.  If you lay them next to each other to spell a word, up/down or right/left there's no problem.  But my tiles go off at an angle (with some overlap), making a diagonal.  Instead of a smooth sequence of data blocks, I get what we used to call 'Jaggies' or a jagged edge.  I want to rotate each tile as I lay it down so the data they repesent will lineup, just as it would if I orient the tiles Up/down or right/left.  Does that make sense?  If can only align my 'tiles' Up/down, the only Track that works is North/South.

Comment: Sorry, you lost me at "I want to rotate each tile as I lay it down so the data they repesent will lineup"

Comment: Each block of data my sensors record is a rectangle.  On a map, oriented North on the top, each Ascii file of data becomes a small rectangle, rt/left sides are aligned with true North.  However, the sled moved at say a heading of NW, making a strip of sensor readings.  But when these blocks of data appear on the overall map, they march off at 45 degs and do not make a continuous strip of pixels.  Each block steps up and over, staying N/S not rotated in the direction of the heading NW, much like a stairs.  I want a ramp, not stairs. OK?

Comment: What would be perfect for my purposes is a command line option that ROTATES the block of data away from the default N/S alignment, taking on any degree of rotation I input.

Comment: By "Arc Ascii" do you mean [**Esri ASCII Raster**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009t0000000z000000) format?  If so, could you edit your question to clarify that, please?  Now, before anyone has attempted to answer, would also be a good time to revise your question through an extensive edit to address @underdark's requests for clarification too.

Comment: I believe you need to do more than just rotate it: you need to locate your file properly within a coordinate system common to all of them so they can be mosaiced (or otherwise merged) into a spatially consistent representation of the data that were collected. In short, it sounds like you wish automatically to *geoereference* a collection of files based on information about the location and bearing of the sensor array associated with each file. It's too much to expect such a complex and specialized function to be available out of the box: you will need to program it.

Comment: Each file already has a GPS coordinate, top left corner.  If possible, I want to compose a command line that would 'georeference' each input file, hopefully rotating it along the heading that generated the data originally.  Then I could later collect these raster maps for more rapid display, ie, joining raster files in Qgis, already answered.  What is the syntax for 'georeference' when inputing one Esri Ascii file to produce a rotated raster map?